# Showing the employees who are out of office on modern site page

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, people-search, modern-experience, modern-pages

I am working on a new SharePoint online classic team site, and I have added a new modern page where I set it as the home page for the team site. Now, we got the following requirement from our customer:

1. On the modern site page, show all the employees who are out of office and the date when they will return back. something as follow:

[image]

so I am not sure if sharepoint online provides an out of the box modern web part to achieve this?

OR if I can write a cusotm JavaScript to show these information (I can add a JavaScript inside our modern pages since I am using this web part [react-script-editor](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor)).

Now, if there is no out of the box solution, then what are the approaches I can follow to achieve this requirement?

Note: inside our office 365 tenant if we click on a username we gets redirected to the user's Delve page, so not sure if we can benefit from this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No, SharePoint online doesn't provide out of the box solutions to acheive this.

- You can use react script editor!
- Or create a list for out of office users,

  1. calaculate the coming date
  2. modify view to show  the employee as this filter

     ```
       [coming date] > TODAY
     ```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. First Question, now i am already using  "react script editor" inside my sites, but how i can benefit from this to achieve what i am looking for? Second Question, for your second point, you mean to add a list and then to manually manage the users who are out of office , is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct

Comment: which point you are referring to as correct? of course i am looking to manage these info manually.... i am asking about getting the out of office employees dynamically..

Comment: As I said, it's not available as OOTB solution, you should develop it! Please accept my answer if it helpful

Comment: which answer you want me to accept !! i am not asking how to build a list to maintain the employees info, which is a basic task to do.. please read my question again.. i am asking about a dynamic way to get the employees who are out of office, from Delve or from their Skype for business  statuses or from any source inside our office 365..

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can develop a small SPFx webpart to fetch the employee status from delve/Users. To fetch the status info from delve/Users you have to use Graph API. I am not sure that the leave details will be available under delve. If it is requires even you can use Outlook data to find the leave details. These all are dynamic data, but it requires Graph API call.

Comment: can you provide more details about using Graph API calls to get the data i am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this out of the box.  It depends on if you have the correct fields or not.  I would suggest a [leave date begin] and a [leave date end] on the list.  You can then create an "out of office" view that has filters today >= [leave date begin] and today <= [leave date end].  You can then just show the view of the list as a web part on your page.

Comment: @LuckyLiny i am not asking how to build a list to maintain the employees info, which is a basic task to do.. please read my question again.. i am asking about a dynamic way to get the employees who are out of office, from Delve or from lync statuses